# How to create puppet external structured facts from script, such as python or bash?

Tags: puppet, fact, facter

I have seen the documentation, especially [External Facts](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6/external_facts.html) and [Custom Facts](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/custom_facts.html).

I have the following `yum_repos.rb`:

```
require 'facter'
Facter.add('yum_repos') do
    setcode '/usr/bin/python3 /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib/facter/yum_repos.py'
end
```

I have the following `yum_repos.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import configparser
import os
import json

result_dict={}
yum_repos_dir = '/etc/yum.repos.d'
for yum_repo_file in os.listdir(yum_repos_dir):
    if not yum_repo_file.endswith(".repo"):
        continue
    yum_repo_name=yum_repo_file.replace(".repo","")
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(os.path.join(yum_repos_dir, yum_repo_file))
    result_dict[yum_repo_name] = {}
    for section in config.sections():
        result_dict[yum_repo_name][section] = dict(config[section])
print(json.dumps(result_dict))
```

When I check facter, it all runs, but the `yum_repos` fact is a string. Why isn't it structured? I found somewhere on the internet, saying (for old versions of puppet) that `stringify_facts` must be set to false, so I tried that, but the behavior did not change. I believe that the [default was changed in 4.0](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-406) to not stringify.

I am using puppet 6.24.0

I try to access the facts in a puppet class like this:

```
if $facts['yum_repos']['redhat']...['enabled'] != 1 {
    ...
}
```

And when I run puppet agent, I get the error message:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: A substring operation does not accept a String as a character index. Expected an Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out why puppet is stringifying the fact, but I was able to workaround by explicitly calling `parsejson()`, like so:

```
if parsejson($facts['yum_repos'])['redhat']...['enabled'] != "1" {
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you create a fact that obtains its value directly from the output of a system command, then how would that *not* come in as a string?

Comment: @JohnBollinger All the puppet/facter documentation referenced above says if you output json, yaml, or certain other structured formats, then it is parsed automatically by facter into structured data. Except in old versions of puppet (<4.0) where that feature was not enabled by default and needed to be enabled in puppet.conf. After 4.0, it's enabled by default.

Comment: I see.  Well, either the docs where you saw that where unclear about their scope, or you overlooked it: that applies to [*external* facts](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/external_facts.html), not [custom facts implemented via the Ruby API](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/fact_overview.html).